# Setting up pip in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, easy-install

I've installed `easy_install` and `setuptools` in `Python 2.7`. I'm having a nightmare while installing `pip` using `easy_install pip`. I've followed my SO posts and blogs, but still no help.

Following is the error I receive in my Windows `cmd`:

```
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target mac
hine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target mac
hine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line
434, in easy_install
    self.local_index
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 475, in
 fetch_distribution
    return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

Comment: First check whether you can do this step `C:\Users\xyz>pip install
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think during your attempts you have messed up your Python setup somehow. While I am sure that you can get things working with just the CPython installer from python.org (I and many others did this), I strongly recommend to start over (cleanly remove what you have so far) and install one of the Python distributions that have some more features, for example:

- [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython)
- the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) (EPD) or
- [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/).

They come with several additional packages installed, including pip. Their installer also sets up your Windows PATH properly. So, after running the installer, you can just go ahead, start `cmd.exe` and run `python` or `pip install ...`

The free version of EPD can be found [here](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php). I myself have made good experiences with EPD but also with Python(x,y). [Here](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins) is a list of "plugins" that the standard Python(x,y) installer brings along. Note that for Windows both, EPD and Python(x,y), are only available as 32 Bit version ... however, ActivePython for Windows 64-bit is free (PyPM packages are not free for 64-bit). Depending on your needs, this might not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I did this I am working With Windows 7 x64.

```
                        Installing Python 2.7
```

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2
--------Windows x86 MSI Installer (2.7.2) (sig)

After python 2.7 is installed(I installed by default at c:\python27) so you are ready.

```
                           **Installing PIP:**
```

Download the file get-pip.py

https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py

Save it, in a known Folder: c:\pip\

Go to Windows - Run - Type  cmd.exe

Inside cmd.exe type:

cd c:\python27(or the route where you installed python)

You will see this:

c:\python27

now type (Remember the route where you saved get-pip.py our Case c:\pip).

c:\python27\ python.exe c:\pip\get-pip.py

Pip will be installed.

```
                       Using Pip to Install Django
```

Now with Python and Pip installed Go to Windows - Run - Type  cmd.exe

Inside cmd.exe type:

cd c:\python27

You will see this:

c:\python27

now type

python.exe -m pip install xxxxxxx

Pip will install your xxxxxx desired package.

Example:
pip install Django==1.6.2

NOTE: THIS GUIDE IS FOR TOTALLY NEWBIES AT PYTHON AND WINDOWS.

Regards

erick.alfaro@adtein.com
www.adtein.com

Answer (score 1):

i went to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip
there is a tar you can download from there.
after downloading just run "easy_install pip-1.3.1.tar.gz" from command prompt in your Python\Scripts folder.
seems to do the job.
hope this helps